# How to open dialer on click of ListView

Tags: android

I have one application in which list view is there in that list view number and button is there and I want that button click number goes to dial screen...
Please suggest

Answer (score 3):

i think you are asking for call functionality, try below code on button click,

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL); 
intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + "2356894745"));
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 2):

you can try this way:

```
phone.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

           Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL); 
           intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + "12345"));
           startActivity(intent); 

        }
    });
```

**The 'tel:' prefix is required**, otherwhise the following exception will be thrown:
*java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity.*

**Action_Dial doesn't require any permission.**

If you want to call the number immediatly , You can use action `Intent.ACTION_CALL`. In this case, you must add the following permission in your AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

Answer (score 1):

public class Help_Ambulance extends ListActivity {

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle abc){
    //super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    super.onCreate(abc);
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    HashMap<String, String> item = new HashMap<String, String>();
    HashMap<String, String> item2 = new HashMap<String, String>();
    HashMap<String, String> item3 = new HashMap<String, String>();
    HashMap<String, String> item4 = new HashMap<String, String>();
    HashMap<String, String> item5 = new HashMap<String, String>();
    HashMap<String, String> item6 = new HashMap<String, String>();
    HashMap<String, String> item7 = new HashMap<String, String>();
    HashMap<String, String> item8 = new HashMap<String, String>();
    HashMap<String, String> item9 = new HashMap<String, String>();
    HashMap<String, String> item10 = new HashMap<String, String>();

    item.put("name", "Pune Ambulance");
    item.put("number", "101");
    item.put("address", "Pune City");

    item2.put("name", "Jeevan Jyoti Services");
    item2.put("number", "02067288011");
    item2.put("address", "Nali Road, Hadapsar");

    item3.put("name", "Bharat Ambulance Services");
    item3.put("number", "02066823158");
    item3.put("address", "Hospital Vallabh Nagar, Pimpri");        

    item4.put("name", "Lokmangal Ambulance Services");
    item4.put("number", "02040422273");
    item4.put("address", "Hospital, Deccan Gymkhana");        

    item5.put("name", "Deendayal Memorial Hospital");
    item5.put("number", "02025652497");
    item5.put("address", "Paduka, Fergusson College Road");        

    item6.put("name", "Ruby Hall Clinic");
    item6.put("number", "02026121099");
    item6.put("address", "Bund Garden Road, Pune");        

    item7.put("name", "Sahyadri Hospital");
    item7.put("number", "02025403000");
    item7.put("address", "");        

    item8.put("name", "Deenanath Mangeshkar Hospital Ambulance Services");
    item8.put("number", "02040151000");
    item8.put("address", "Erandwane");        

    item9.put("name", "Jehangir Hospital");
    item9.put("number", "02026121066");
    item9.put("address", "Pune Station, Pune");    

    item10.put("name", "Kolumbus Ambulance And Healthcare");
    item10.put("number", "02066826189");
    item10.put("address", "Shirole Road, Shivaji Nagar");    

    list.add(item);
    list.add(item2);
    list.add(item3);
    list.add(item4);
    list.add(item5);
    list.add(item6);
    list.add(item7);
    list.add(item8);
    list.add(item9);
    list.add(item10);


    String[] columns = new String[] { "name", "number", "address" };
    int[] renderTo = new int[] { R.id.name, R.id.number, R.id.address };

    ListAdapter listAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, list,   R.layout.help_ambulance_row, columns, renderTo);

    setListAdapter(listAdapter);
}
```

}